# Understanding MySql queries

Tags: mysql

Trying to teach my self a bit of mysql and php and decided to do that by working on actual project with help oh "how to do everything with MySQL and PHP book".

first problem i have is with understanding joint table queries.

here are my tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE `clients` (
    `id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `client` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `KlientID` (`id`)
    )
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=8;

CREATE TABLE `facilities` (
`id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `facility` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `fk_client` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `fk_idklijent_idx` (`fk_client`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_client_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_client`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=35;

CREATE TABLE `models` (
    `id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `model` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `fk_manufacturer` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `ModelID` (`id`),
    INDEX `fk_proizvodjacID_idx` (`fk_manufacturer`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_manuf_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_manufacturer`) REFERENCES `manufacturers` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=9;

CREATE TABLE `machines` (
    `id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `serial` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `fk_model` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
    `InvBr` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fk_facilities` SMALLINT(6) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sw` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `adaptation` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_uredjaji_modeli` (`fk_model`),
    INDEX `FK_uredjaji_poslovnice` (`fk_facilities`),
    INDEX `Index 4` (`serial`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_facility_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_facilities`) REFERENCES `facilities` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_models_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_model`) REFERENCES `models` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=93;

CREATE TABLE `technicians` (
    `id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `ServiserID` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

CREATE TABLE `workorders` (
    `id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `wo_nr` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `fk_machine_id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
    `fk_technitian_id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL,
    `counter` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `service_date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `description` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `work_hours` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_rn_serviseri` (`fk_technitian_id`),
    INDEX `FK_machines_id_idx` (`fk_machine_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_machines_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_machine_id`) REFERENCES `machines` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_technitian_id` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_technitian_id`) REFERENCES `technicians` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1393;
```

using this query i get each row 8 times.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT (w.service_date, '%d.%m.%Y'), f.facility, m.model, mc.serial, w.description, t.name
FROM workorders AS w, facilities AS f, models AS m, machines AS mc, technicians AS t
WHERE f.id = mc.fk_facilities AND w.fk_machine_id = mc.id AND w.fk_technitian_id = t.id AND w.service_date > '2009-12-31'
ORDER BY w.service_date DESC;
```

can someone pls point me to what i'm doing wrong. *i only need rows from workorders table. other tables are here only to show real data not only id's* - bad, not true :(

thx

edit 1:
i need a list of workorders. to explain my question little more here is how the result should look like:
[date][name of the facility the machine (fk_machine_id) belongs to][model of the machine (fk_machine_id)][serial number of the machine (fk_machine_id)][description from workorder][technician name (fk_technician_id)]

edit2:

[here is the model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k35bz.png)

i think my problem is in fact that to get the model i need to check with machines table first. Same thing with facility.

Comment: " other tables are here only to show real data not only id's" what do you mean by this?

Comment: Just as a reference point: this is a great article explaining joins http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: @A Paul: that actually is just my bad english. i do need data from other tables to replace id's from workorder table and for some extra info. i've edited my question, not sure if it helps.

Comment: @xQbert: thx. will look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

got it!

the problem was in one missing AND.

final SELECT looks like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT (w.service_date, '%d.%m.%Y') AS service_date, w.wo_nr, f.facility, m.model, mc.serial, FORMAT (w.counter, 0) AS Counter, w.description, t.name AS technician 
FROM workorders AS w, technicians AS t, machines AS mc, models AS m, facilities AS f
WHERE mc.fk_facilities = f.id 
AND w.fk_machine_id = mc.id 
AND mc.fk_model = m.id 
AND w.fk_technitian_id = t.id 
AND w.service_date > '2009-12-31'
ORDER BY w.service_date DESC;
```

thx all. moving on to the next problem :)

Answer (score 0):

to get only rows from workorders table use this query

```
SELECT w.*
FROM workorders AS w, facilities AS f, models AS m, machines AS mc, technicians AS t
WHERE f.id = mc.fk_facilities AND w.fk_machine_id = mc.id AND w.fk_technitian_id = t.id AND w.service_date > '2009-12-31'
ORDER BY w.service_date DESC;
```

Comment: i do not know how to answer to all so i'll just use your answer for that Volkan. First of all thx all for your suggestions and sorry on my bad english.

Comment: @suspectus, and others. i'm not sure if this is a right way to to answer all so i'll just use your answer for that Volkan. First of all thx all for your suggestions and sorry on my bad english. if i just list workorders table i'll get this results: service date, technician id, machine id description. each machine belongs to some client. and is of some model. so for data to be more readable i need machine model, machine serial number and facility it belongs to. not sure if that was more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You say you only want data from the workorders table. Then you don't need all the other joins.

```
SELECT * FROM workorders WHERE service_date > '2009-12-31'
```

Unless you need the columns in their tables as well.

Not too sure exactly what you require though.

Comment: he said "first problem i have is with understanding joint table queries." so he is testing joins i guess.

Comment: In that case it's fine to have the joins as in your answer. While learning you can include the joins. Yet keep in mind going forward when developing for production keep the joins relavant to the required data. If you only need data from one table and there are no where clauses requiring other tables, then stick to just 1 table. It's faster that way.

Comment: sry Methedex. i have expressed my self wrong. please read my other comments. maybe i'll help. thx

Answer (score 0):

Only put the columns you want returned in your results set in the SELECT section of your query. You can still include columns from other tables in your joins, they just won't be displayed. Also if you are getting multiple rows then either your data contains duplicates in which case you should look at your keys and constraints or you are missing one or more joins.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT (w.service_date, '%d.%m.%Y') as service_date,  
f.facility, m.model, mc.serial, w.description, t.name
FROM workorders AS w, facilities AS f, models AS m, machines AS mc, technicians AS t
WHERE f.id = mc.fk_facilities 
AND w.fk_machine_id = mc.id 
AND w.fk_technitian_id = t.id 
AND w.service_date > '2009-12-31'
ORDER BY w.service_date DESC;
```

Comment: thx Ashalynd. i do need all the data from the select statement. the key is fk_machine_id filed that tels what facility and what model. also id like to have technician name not hes id. that's why technicians table to.

Comment: Ah that makes it more clear :) Going to edit my answer.

Comment: thx Ashalynd. but this gives me exactly the same result as my original query. there are only 4 records in the workorders table that are newer than 2009-12-31. And in my result i get 32 records. I'm guessing that i'm probably short of one more WHERE.